# Finding bounding rectangle after rotation

Tags: trigonometry

[image: fig depicting problem]

I have two rectangles  inner rectangle(green) and the outer one (red).

OuterRectangle will be calculated by adding some offset to inner rectangle as shown below.

OuterLeft = innerLeft - 100;
OuterTop = innerTop - 100;
OuterRight = innerRight + 100;
OuterBottom = innerBottom + 100;

But this will not work once the inner rectangle is rotated .
Please let me know how can i calculate outer rectangle based on inner rectangle after rotation by some angle.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "figure out the outer rectangle"? Do you mean figure out the equations of the lines of the outer rectangle?

Comment: No only top,left,bottom and right corners of outer rectangle

Answer (score 0):

If you knew the rotation angle, you could simply apply the same rotation to the outer rectangle. So I assume that you only have to corner points of the (rotated) inner rectangle.

Let $p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3$ be the points of the inner rectangle, ordered counterclockwise (starting at the upper left corner, in this case). Then you can compute the vectors describing the edges

- $e_0 = p_1 - p_0$
- $e_1 = p_2 - p_1$
- $e_2 = p_3 - p_2$
- $e_3 = p_0 - p_3$

and the corresponding directions, by normalizing these vectors

$d_i = e_i / |e_i|$ for $i = 0...3$

The corners of the outer rectangle can then be computed based on the original points and these direction vectors. Let $s_t, s_l, s_b, s_r$ denote the offset of the outer rectangle at the top, left, bottom and right side, respectively (in your case, they are all 100).

- $q_0 = p_0 - s_t d_0 + s_l d_3$
- $q_1 = p_1 - s_l d_1 + s_b d_0$
- $q_2 = p_2 - s_b d_2 + s_r d_1$
- $q_3 = p_3 - s_r d_3 + s_t d_2$

(This is not really related to trigonometry, by the way)

Comment: i have rotation angle of inner rectangle , but simply rotating outer rectangle will not work because 
consider the scenario where  inner rectangle is rotated and after rotation if dimensions are also scaled
in that case simply rotating outer rectangle will not work  . So any inputs ??
Pardon my ignorance about tagging to trignometry.

Comment: My answer describes the solution for the case that you do **not** know the rotation angle. It shows how you can compute the outer rectangle when you *only* know the points of the inner rectangle.

Comment: I understand it .Thanks for the feed back .

Comment: I understand it .Thanks for the feed back.But what i am asking is  , assume that we know the rotation angle now consider the inner rectangle is rotated 
and after rotation dimensions are also scaled . for ex after rotating inner rectangle (left ,top) &(right , bottom )
could be (50,50) and (100,150) respectively assume now i scale the dimension by changing (right,bottom) to 
(200,250) . In this scenario how can we calculate outer rectangle where inner rectangle is rotated and scaled ??

Comment: It depends on how the transformations are given. They could, for example, be a sequence of affine transformations (2x2 matrices, or 3x3 if you also want to cover translations). However, with the method that I described, you can compute the new rectangle, regardless of how the old rectangle is transformed.